# python unittest and pytest - can I assign test status to a variable

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I am working on a python based testing system, that iterates through a set of python tests and run them one by one (there are unittests and pytests).

Is there a way that my testing system to understand the result of every individual tests and saves it to a dictionary with key [test_name]  and value [test_status] for example. I imagine if the result of the test to be assigned to a variable for example:

```
test_status = "passed"
```

PS: all of the tests have a main(), that looks like that

```
# for unittests
def main():
    unittest.main()

# for pytests
def main():
    os.system("py.test -v {}".format(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Why the distinction between the two? pytest should be able to run unittest.py-style tests just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for unittest framework:

The idea is to change the test ouput data to be not on the terminal console, but to a file. One way to do it is to add the following code to the tests:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # terminal command to run a specific test and save its output to a log file
    # python [this_module_name] [log_file.log] [*tests]
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('test_log_file')
    parser.add_argument('unittest_args', nargs='*')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    log_file = sys.argv[1]
    # Now set the sys.argv to the unittest_args (leaving sys.argv[0] alone)
    sys.argv[1:] = args.unittest_args

    with open(log_file, "w") as f:
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f)
        unittest.main(defaultTest=sys.argv[2:], exit=False, testRunner=runner)
```

and run it with command like this one:

```
python my_tests.py log_file.log class_name.test_1 class_name.test_2 ... test_n
```

Other way is with direct command that looks like this one:

```
python -m unittest [test_module_name].[test_class_name].[test_name] 2> [log_file_name]
# real command example:
python -m unittest my_tests.class_name.test_1 2> my_test_log_file.log
# real command example with multiple tests:
python -m unittest my_tests.class_name.test_1 my_tests.class_name.test_2 my_tests.class_name.test_3 2> my_test_log_file.log
```

The final part is to write a method, that reads this log file and get the result of the test. Those log files look something like that:

```
.FEs
======================================================================
ERROR: test_simulative_error (__main__.SimulativeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest_tests.py", line 84, in test_simulative_error
    raise ValueError
ValueError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_simulative_fail (__main__.SimulativeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest_tests.py", line 81, in test_simulative_fail
    assert False
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1, skipped=1)
```

So the final step is to open that log_file and read the first line that gives information how the test/tests have finished and save this info as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to *actually run* pytest or unittests as a *command line tool* and retrieve the results.

The straightforward way to do this would be to use **JUnit xml output** and parse it. For example in pytest:

```
pytest --junitxml=path
```

Maybe you want to consider using an automation server like Jenkins, that will run unittests and pytest tests separately and then collect the results.

Comment: Yeah, I use Jenkins. Actually I have solved this problem, and in the following days when I have a little bit time, I will post the solution in here.